# How can i ignore some intent keys in this program

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to ignore some intent keys that are null because user didn't input any value for them in 1st interval of my program. Take a look:

```
Intent getAll = getIntent();
//this value is entered and is from Activity A.
String b_spnr1 = getAll.getStringExtra("intnt_bSP1");
//Dosnt have any value yet and came from Activity B.
double[] dead_wght = getAll.getDoubleArrayExtra("dead_intnt");
```

If I run this (enter a value for activity A) and want to see it here and ignore from entering value for activity B, i got NullpointerException error.

How can I change this code to get value which is inserted and ignore absentee of other value from Activity B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use intent.hasExtra("key") to check if the intent contains the perticular key.

Comment: like getAll.hasExtra("dead_wght")?  ok,but idontknow what to do if it hasnt the key!!

Comment: If it doesn't contain the key, don't try to retrieve it.